# How should we deal with people misusing the [Visual-Studio] and [Android-Studio] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

From the tag description for the [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) tag:

> Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) from Microsoft. **Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality, not just a question regarding your code.** Consider tagging the exact technology area your question links to and also tagging a more specific version of Visual Studio. Please mention your exact VS version, edition, and update level in your question.

Similarly for the [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) tag:

> Use for questions about using Android Studio, an official IDE targeted at Android development. **Do NOT use for questions about programming for Android in general; instead use [android].**

And yet, I see dozens of questions (mostly by new users) that tag general programming questions with these tags. It seems like it tends to crowd out legitimate questions about the tools themselves.

Is there a way to prevent this (without manually editing after the fact)?

Comment: maybe all our guidance needs to fit in 140 characters? More text will not compute in the upcoming twitter generation.

Comment: See also: ["Xcode is just an IDE"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93974/xcode-is-just-an-ide). If you have an IDE, people will tag generic language questions with it. Trying to fight it can feel like trying to hold back the tide. Don't know that there'll ever be a good solution for this.

Comment: When I was new, I added all the tags that were remotely related because I thought it would have people understand the stack I was using. I didn't think of it as classifying the question types.

Comment: @TankorSmash Good point - maybe the site tour should have a bit more on that or something? (Not that the majority of people read the tour before posting).

Comment: This is the result of "more never hurts" mentality. I repeatedly complained back then... sigh...

Comment: It feels like this has risen (again?) recently ...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a major annoyance to me with Android Studio.  The problem is that the casual/low information user who does this isn't going to read a tag wiki.

I would say that if you submit a question with the tag android-studio, you should get a popup:

> You used the [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) tag.  This tag should only be for questions on how to use the editing software, and not how to write a program using it.  Use this tag anyway?

and require them to click through.  That might cut down on it.  But the type of person who doesn't know the difference between an IDE, a language, and a platform likely is just going to hit "yes" anyway.

Comment: I agree with this feature idea. It seems like the fact that the practice is so widespread is also a bit of a "broken window" (i.e. the fact that the tag description's not more strictly enforced leads people to think that it's OK for them to do it too).

Comment: That would be too annoying and overkill. The slippery slope is now every tag ends up with a pop up. It needs to be more restrictive when it would show. The only solution is to just edit the tags. Think of it as a typo, not a major issue.

Comment: @StarWind It definitely could go that way.  But I don't think editing the tags teaches anything.  They don't notice it, and if they do they don't understand why.  Great example-  I just talked to someone on Android who posted a bad question on how to get address info from a server to Android Studio.  When I tried to explain that AndroidStudio was just a fancy notepad he totally didn't understand.  That's the level of user we're frequently dealing with.

Comment: True, there is always that level of user. I deal with many 1 point users in the stackoverflow 3d printing group. I'd say a good 20% of our questions end up being closed. That said I didn't expand on the criteria. I do not know it is possible. but maybe we see someone post combos of tags, ie JAVA and Android studio. That would trigger the event. Its rare it would be a java and IDE issue.

Comment: @GabeSechan "But I don't think editing the tags teaches anything" coupled with the fact that [the system doesn't notify them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/213575)

Comment: An alternative: just have this for low-reputation users the first couple of times they use one of those tags.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to expand from @GabeSechan's answer.

A popup on clicking post is a good idea, but limiting it to Android STudio isn't enough. This should be added to every IDE, as those tags are used wrong in most likely all the IDE's to some or another extent. In some cases, it can be a minor amount of questions that are irrelevant (no examples) and in others it can be much more (like ANdroid Studio and Visual Studio).

I have seen through the Android Studio tag, and there is an extreme amount of questions that have nothing to do with ANdroid Studio except the code being written in it. I haven't checked VS, but AS has an extreme amount of these questions. I have no clue why it is used either.

ANother thing that can **and should** trigger this popup is if the question is tagged for an instance [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) - basically if the IDE **AND** programming language/platform is tagged. It should still trigger on IDE only ([android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio)).

I don't have stats on this, so I have no clue what users often abuse it. By what users I mean rep-based (and maybe experience-based). Having that popup permanently isn't a good idea, yet we can't add a checkbox that says "Got it, don't show this message again". Having it based on tag score and/or user rep is a good idea to target it. Showing it once isn't enough, as few learn from one popup. Another thing it could do is check the first question after the popup is added to question-writing. If the first question has its tag **removed** and/or receives comments that it has nothing to do with Android STudio the popup should be shown on the next question.

The popup should also have a "timeout". By this I mean it takes x seconds from it shows until it is dismissable to ensure the users read through the content and make sure they understand. Alternatively "hide" the "yes/no" button under a scroll fold which means they have to scroll a bit to see the buttons.

And again, there is only so many questions we can hope to prevent from using the AS/VS/other IDE tags, but a little improvement is better than no improvement. ANd the more a popup can prevent, the less has to be edited