# Is tag spamming or blatant mis-tagging a legitimate reason to downvote a question?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Related: [How should we deal with people misusing the [Visual-Studio] and [Android-Studio] tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346150/how-to-deal-with-people-misusing-the-visual-studio-and-android-studio-tags)

If a question was blatantly mis-tagged (e.g. they use the [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) tag for a general programming question that had nothing to do with the tool or the OP blatantly spams tags and/or tags unrelated languages), is this a legitimate reason to downvote the question (assuming that the question is otherwise reasonable)?

Comment: i mean... you can downvote for whatever reason you want. but it would probably be more constructive to just fix the problem.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I typically edit and comment explaining that they misused the tag (especially if I'm downvoting - it's rude and unconstructive to downvote without explanation IMHO because then the OP can't improve), just not sure if downvoting's appropriate if I already fixed it. My thought process is that poor tagging is a form of lack of research effort on the OP's part.

Comment: Right... but once you fix it, the question doesn't have that problem anymore. Votes should be cast on the post's merits, not the user's.

Comment: @KevinB Good point, that's why I asked. So you think that commenting and editing is sufficient? (That could probably be an answer to the question if so).

Comment: Why wouldn't it be sufficient? If you fix the thing you were going to downvote for, there's no longer a reason to downvote, right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic you're right.  So, just downvote it - it's a bad question and downvoting is one click - may as well expend the least effort possible on such questions.  The OP can fix the tag issue, if it wants.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I was going for. I just meant, fix or downvote, but not both, because doing both doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Downvote, don't fix, next..

Comment: I get that that's your opinion, but no, I _do not_ agree with it. Please stop implying that I do.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, do you, or @Don'tPanic, have an example where tags were spammed AND the question was otherwise reasonable?

Comment: No, I haven't looked for any. This question says "assuming that the question is otherwise reasonable", so I assumed. I agree with you that if a question has a bunch of silly tags, it's probably _not_ otherwise reasonable, but that's not what this question is asking about.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That's a good point, actually - there's a good chance that such a question *wouldn't* be otherwise reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consensus seems to be to *either* edit and comment *or* downvote (and maybe comment), but not all three.

Comment: I'm confused why you think that is the consensus. Why would you downvote, which means the "question does not show any research effort, or is unclear or not useful"? Does a spurious tag make the entire question unclear or not useful? Why is editing without a comment not an option? Any OP with half a brain should be able to intuit that the tag was removed because someone thought it was inappropriate, with or without the benefit of a comment. And no, poor tagging is not a form of lack of research.

Comment: @torazaburo You bring up valid points - that could probably be an answer, actually. Also, I agree that the summary I gave here is probably less than perfect, which is why I added it as community wiki hoping that someone could help me improve it.

Comment: 'Does a spurious tag make the entire question unclear or not useful?' - one would think not, but I'm betting that an analysis of the tag-spammed questions against their quality would show a large correlation.

Comment: @torazaburo Some of it depends, too, on what "research effort" means. You could argue that tag-spamming reflects a lack of effort to formulate their question well.

Answer (score 2):

Preferred (from site's point of view) action on otherwise good question is to edit tags to match question.

If question deserves downvote even if you *would* edit tags - go ahead and cast one. Whether to edit tags in this case is your call, but if your edits require review (<2k rep) then skip editing as you already decided that your edit will not make whole question to be meet SO quality bar. In this case broad tags (even if blatantly mis-tagged like using IDE tag "visual-studio" or "java" on JavaScript question) may actually help to get more eyes on the post and triage it sooner.