# Why was my flag for moderation declined for a (still) unclear question?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, self-answer

I have difficulty in trying to understand why a recent flag I raised for moderation for the following question was declined:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572238/unable-to-post-data-to-mysql-from-android

> *"I voted too soon, as in "unclear" because the question was unclear and they should have posted the relevant php from the beginning. I asked for clarification to post the relevant php and they did not. Instead, they posted their own answer that they missed a comma. I find the question should be deleted since it will only serve their own purpose."*

...and got back

> *"declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*

My casted vote was *"unclear what you're asking"*, since the question was unclear for the following reason:

- It did not contain the code to support the question being "php" related (or mysql for that matter), as per the OP's answer:

> *"Nevermind. It was the PHP i missed a comma!"*

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43572343/1415724

I asked for clarification in comments (from what you can see; given if it's still alive), and I got nothing back, where they posted an answer of their own with no code to support the question, making this ***"all their own",*** in turn preventing anyone else from posting an answer and/or by closing it with the (possible) duplicate(s) for it that are already in place, being:

- [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)
- [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Should my flag have contained my requesting to delete the question since it will serve no purpose to anyone other than their own?

There should have been more votes to close as unclear from the moment it was posted.

IMHO, the question should be deleted since there has been no further updates or responses to my comments.

Comment: The post in question has since been deleted - can you post a screenshot for those of us with less than 10K rep?

Comment: @EJoshuaS What's the point?  There was a question that he thinks was unclear, he flagged it for the reason stated.  You don't need to see the question to know why the flag was declined.  The meta question *already* has enough information for an answer.  This meta question has more than enough superfluous information already, it doesn't need *more*.

Comment: @Servy That's true, I think that the Meta post has enough information even without the image, I was just curious to see what post we were actually talking about.

Answer (score 15):

If you think a question should be closed then cast a close vote; don't flag for a moderator.  Your flag was correctly declined because moderators are there to handle issues that the community can't handle, and closing an unclear question is something that the community can handle.

You should not flag a question for deletion because the OP found out it was a typo.  That too is a close reason; feel free to cast a close vote for it.  You can even vote to delete the question, once closed, if you feel that's appropriate (although the question would likely end up being deleted automatically if closed as it is negatively scored).

Comment: I agree only to a certain point; I've pretty much done everything *by the book*. However, since the question was never updated and their answer doesn't support the question and the tags used; if I'd removed the "php/mysql" tags, what then? The question would've been even more unclear. I hope you understand my point of view here. That's why IMHO the question should've been deleted from the moment I flagged it; it has not served anyone's purpose other than their own. I do "respect the mods' decision(s), but that doesn't necessarily mean I have to agree fully; I too have a say/voice in all this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, you didn't do things, "by the book".  You did things very wrong.  When you see a question that merits closure, you should vote to close it, not flag it for moderator attention.  Flagging for a mod because a question is unclear *is wrong*, and as a result, the flag was *correctly* declined.  If the question does end up being closed, you can *also* cast a delete vote if you feel the question is unsalvageable, and that is *also* not something you should be flagging a moderator for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree with Servy here; there's no reason for the mods to intervene here - just downvote and vote to close.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The question was bad. It should have been closed and deleted. No disagreements here on that matter. However, it didn't require _immediate_ deletion, which would have indeed been a reason to grab the mods. There was nothing extremely out there about this post, it was your run of the mill bad post. At worst, it lingers on the site a short time before the roomba destroys it. At best, three 20k users or a mod stumble upon it shortly and it gets deleted faster. However, it is not rude, abusive, spam, etc. so it really doesn't require mod intervention in any way.

Comment: @Kendra Something being rude/abusive/spam/etc. is *also* not a reason to use a mod flag.  There are specific flag reasons for each of those issues as well, and *those* should be used when you see posts with those problems.

Comment: @Servy Agreed and correct, ran out of room for that part. (I at least only said "require mod intervention" and not specifically flags)

Comment: @Kendra Those flags often don't even need mod intervention.  Lots and lots of spam and offensive content is handled by community flagging, without requiring moderator involvement.

Comment: @Servy What do you mean when you say that _Something being rude/abusive/spam/etc. is also not a reason to use a mod flag_ - Shouldn't I alert mods if I see spam related content, or if a user being  bluntly rude and abusive to others? Why letting this user to enjoy the liberty of just having a first/second/third warning, instead of taking an immediate action against them?

Comment: @AlonEitan No, you *shouldn't* use a custom mod flag if you see spam or abusive content.  You should use the flag *specifically created for that exact purpose*.  That's *why those flag reasons exist*.  If we never wanted anyone to flag spam as spam, and instead want them to use a custom moderator flag, then *there wouldn't be a flag reason for it in the first place*.  If you use the wrong flag reason then you're just going to run into the issue Fred here is having where a mod declines your flag, telling you to use the proper flag reason.

Comment: @Servy Oh, I thought you meant that flagging this type of actions to mods is wrong altogether. Thanks

Comment: @AlonEitan Spam and rude or abusive flags may or may not entail moderator attention; a question'll be automatically deleted if enough people flag if I remember correctly, plus it's a little faster for the mods to review if it goes to them.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Sometimes I don't want the system (or the community) to simply delete it and carry on, I want those pricks also be punished if what they did was intentional and not in good faith, but I will try to flag it correctly and choose a specific flag (if such available) rather than a custom one

Comment: @AlonEitan Good point - I actually asked about what the punishment for being flagged rude/abusive/spam is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348371/what-are-the-typical-punishments-for-having-a-post-found-to-be-rude-abusive-or), apparently they'll typically get punished for having stuff deleted for being spam/rude/abusive too

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Servy on this one - there's no reason for the moderators to intervene here just because it's a lousy question; there are already plenty of actions that the community can take (downvote, comment, vote to close, and vote to delete). In cases like this, just downvote, vote to close, and comment explaining what's wrong with the question. (Personally, I almost always comment if I'm the first downvoter because I think that downvotes without explanation are counterproductive since they don't help the OP improve).

The fact that something should have been closed faster also isn't really a reason to flag for moderator attention. There are, admittedly, questions that "slip through the cracks" because of close votes "ageing away," but that's a separate issue. If you're interested, I have a Meta question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342457/why-is-the-close-queue-so-much-more-full-than-other-queues) as to why the close queue is so much more full than other review queues and what we should do about that.

In terms of the mis-tagging issue, there's a discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347806/is-tag-spamming-or-blatant-mis-tagging-a-legitimate-reason-to-downvote-a-question) as to whether that's a legitimate reason to downvote a question.

There's always the Close Voters chat room, too, but I've never tried that myself to be honest.

There are, of course, some reasons why you'd want to vote to close *and* flag it for moderator attention. For example, I recently encountered a question asking for help trying to make a virus undetectable. The question showed zero research effort, so it was heavily downvoted and closed as too broad, but I also flagged it for moderator attention because it [violated the terms of service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283570/should-questions-asking-for-illegal-content-be-deleted) and was obviously illegal. (See the linked Meta question for discussion on how to handle questions asking for help doing something that's obviously malicious or illegal).

If a post is rude or abusive or is obvious spam, it should also be flagged along with voting to close; however, as @Servy mentioned in a comment, these should be flagged as spam or rude/abusive, not for moderator attention.