# What are the typical punishments for having a post found to be rude/abusive or spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, rude-or-abusive

My understanding is that there are several ways to have a post found to be rude/abusive or spam: either enough people flag the post as rude/abusive/spam that the system auto-deletes the post or someone flags a post as rude/abusive/spam and a moderator reviews it and agrees with that.

My understanding is that the number of votes required to do so differs by what kind of post it was (comment, question, answer).

What are the usual penalties for having a post (question, comment, or answer) found to be rude/abusive/spam? Is there some kind of auto-penalty (e.g. reputation loss, suspension, etc.), or only if a moderator determines that there should be one? Does the penalty for offensive comments differ from offensive questions or answers?

Does the penalty differ by post type (comment vs. question vs. answer) or by the way that it was determined to be rude/abusive/spam? For example, is there a bigger penalty for having the community determine that a comment is offensive vs. having a moderator make the same determination?

**Note:** I'm not just asking about comments - I'm asking about different kinds of posts, too. Part of the entire point of the question is the difference between the way comments, questions, and answers are treated.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor

Comment: @vaultah that one focuses on comments. Some vital parts (e.g. the six flags) are missing there, so I vote to leave it open for now.

Comment: @vaultah Glorfindel is correct, this question isn't a duplicate of the one you linked to because that one focuses only on comments whereas mine is asking about questions and answers too. In fact, part of the point of my question is to ask about the differences between how different kinds of posts are treated.

Comment: Trust me, the punishment is very bad. Er... that's what a friend told me. A rude friend. Yeah, that's right.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This question is asking about *posts* too.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If a post hits 6 community spam / offensive flags, it is immediately deleted and locked, one downvote is added per flag, and the posting user receives a 100-point reputation penalty. Additionally, the system starts putting restrictions into place to limit further posts from that user's location.

If a moderator casts a spam flag, it is immediately binding and triggers all of the above without any further flags.

If a moderator simply deletes a post with spam flags on it, the spam flags are marked as helpful, the additional downvotes for those spam flags are added to the post, but the 100-point penalty is not applied. The system also doesn't apply the immediate location-based restrictions on further posts.

In the vast majority of cases where the 100-point penalty is applied and a moderator notices, the account is also destroyed. Similarly, it's relatively rare for a moderator to accept a spam flag but only delete. Usually, we'll decline flags if it clearly wasn't spam / offensive, or dispute (clear) flags if we can see why someone thought it was spam but it really wasn't.

The few outlier cases tend to be when you have an otherwise good account that all of a sudden posts something bizarre. Sometimes it's a compromised account, sometimes people leave themselves logged in at a shared computer, etc.

Comment: Since mod flags are casted anonymously and only mods can see them, if a user is not being a good boy, will they get a any type of custom warning to avoid a possible punishment, or will they realize it only when it's too late?

Comment: @AlonEitan - If a user is posting true spam, they know what they're doing. Warnings aren't going to help there. If someone is being a little too self-promotional but could otherwise be helped, moderators will provide warnings. A warning is only useful if there's some chance it will cause a change in behavior.

Comment: Last question (I promise) because I'm curious to know how the system works behind the scenes -  I only see questions, answers and comments on SO, is there a different type of method saved for showing a moderator warning notification when the user come back to the site? I'll understand if you'll say that it's inappropriate to ask you this

Comment: @AlonEitan: [Mod messages have a dedicated system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283113/what-does-receiving-a-mod-message-look-like), and notifications for them will show up in the global inbox and in email. They are visible (perpetually) to all diamond mods and to the user, and have limited direct reply capabilities.

Comment: Why is it locked?

Comment: @programmer5000 I'd assume in order to prevent it from being undeleted.

Comment: @BradLarson, Do these rules apply to SO Meta as well as SO? In addition, do they apply to comments as well as posts? OP does specifically ask, "Does the penalty for offensive comments differ from offensive questions or answers?"