# Misusage of [ibm]

Tags: discussion, tags

Though tag wiki of [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) states

> **Use IBM's product name instead, unless you are asking about IBM itself.** International Business Machines is an American multinational technology and consulting firm headquartered in New York. IBM manufactures and sells computer hardware and software, and it offers infrastructure, hosting and consulting services

recently I have encountered with many edit requests (removal of [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm)) in suggested edits queue. And I take a quick look to questions with tag [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm), as far as I see (I did not inspect the whole list, like 2K+) questions are not related to the company itself.

Can we do something about this situation?

Note: This question is not a duplicate of [aforementioned question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348131/1519458). That question is a result of this question as you can see from the accepted answer. And it asks directly for the burnination whereas this one does not.

Comment: I can't see why there should be a tag for IBM.. So, burninate [ibm]?

Comment: The only tag that's impossible to pun.

Comment: @MarounMaroun "[ibm] is a bm"?  Is there a rule the puns must be clean?

Comment: **I** **b**elieve [we should] **m**utilate IBM? **F**ind **u**nd **d**estroy IBM?

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Pun or no pun, IBM definitely should burn.

Comment: Nobody ever got burninated for choosing IBM.

Comment: When were questions about IBM, the company, ever on topic?

Comment: Should be blacklisted as Microsoft and Apple in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333833/should-we-burninate-the-apple-tag

Comment: Use ICBMs on [ibm]

Comment: As one of the top all-time users (11 questions, coming in at number three, which indicates a certain inexactitude in the tag, to say the least) in that tag, I have to say I didn't really realise it existed. However, 57 questions are both ibm and mainframe (which makes sense). However, most of the 700+ mainframe questions will also relate to IBM Mainframes. Some won't (there are other Mainframes, although I try to get those tagged as something else). Anyone up for 700+ changes of mainframe to ibm-mainframe? There's 57 waiting with both tags now.

Comment: As the IBM monitor for the ibm-bluemix tag, I agree that the ibm tag serves no purpose. I even created a macro to remove it from the spreadsheet where I track Bluemix questions.

Comment: Rolled this back since the other question is a true burninate request. You should accept Floern's answer

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346150/how-to-deal-with-people-misusing-the-visual-studio-and-android-studio-tags and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347903/display-a-popup-when-a-low-reputation-user-tags-a-question-with-a-frequently-mis?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Wow, how can this question be a duplicate? It was posted first the duplicate target is a result of this question being asked. Flagged to reopen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can we do something about this situation?

Yes, as it gets clear when looking at the comments above, the solution is to remove the tag entirely.

So I have made a [proposal to blacklist and burninate the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348131/watson-wants-to-get-rid-of-ibm) (though that may be a lot of work).

Comment: Or, to shamelessly promote my pet feature proposal, we could [display a popup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347903/display-a-popup-when-a-low-reputation-user-tags-a-question-with-a-frequently-mis?noredirect=1&lq=1) when a low-reputation user uses this tag

Comment: @EJoshuaS Well, in this case the tag isn't misused, it just shouldn't exist here.

Comment: @Braiam It does seem like it would be hard to write a question about IBM (the company) that was actually on-topic now that you mention it...