# Is this a fair use for "duplicate"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, meta

I have recently asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348059/1519458) about what should be the action regarding the misusage of the [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) tag. After ongoing discussions, Floern writes an answer that as a response to my question he asked [a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348131/watson-wants-to-get-rid-of-ibm) which asks for the burnination of [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) and since I agree with him I accept that as an answer.

However, a few people marked my question as duplicate of this new question which is asked in a response to my question. Isn't this a wrong usage of duplicate?

Comment: Does it matter? People who find your question (which wasn't tagged as a burnination request) are directed to the question where they can take action.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I don't see why we needed that new question in the first place. The original question could have been edited to include the [burninate-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) tag, and the new question would have been a good answer to the original question.

That being said, I don't disagree with it being closed as a duplicate. The new question can be seen as an improved version of the first question, I suppose. But it would also have been perfectly fine to *not* close it.